# Как сохранить файл в кодировке base64 на диск в правильном формате?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Вот код:

```
let base64Data; // файл в кодировке base64
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, base64Data , 'base64');
```

Но когда pdf файл сохраняется, потом уже не открывается и пишет что неправильный формат.

Comment: вы имеджи сохраняете?

Comment: Пробовали последним аргументом `{ encoding: 'base64' }`? Если и это не получится, то скорее всего у вас что то не то с исходным файлом в буфере.